# Как средствами JavaScript проверить, одиночный тег перед нами, или парный?

Tags: javascript

А вот такой вопрос: Возможно ли средствами `JavaScript` проверить одиночный тег перед нами, или парный?
Например обрабатываем мы в цикле группу тегов и хотелось бы знать тег на текущей итерации имеет закрывающий тег или нет? Или вариант только сравнения `tagName` с `"img", "br", "hr" ......`

Comment: Где вы хотите проверять тег?

Comment: составить список незакрываемых тегов

Comment: @Yuri допустим функция отрисовывает кусок DOM дерева поступившего на обработку, на странице, мы можем составить строку `str = '< + item.tagName ..... вставляем атрибуты + >'` а вот имеет ли текущий обрабатываемый элемент закрывающий тег или нет, для дальнейшего составления строки хотелось бы знать....

Comment: Тут надо думать

Comment: @Yuri создать массив с именами одиночных тегов и сравнивать или же запихать в JSON.....

Comment: Без понятия :-)

Comment: @pepel_xD, в данном случае лучше не использовать строку вообще

Comment: @Grundy можете более развернуто пояснить?